# How to restrict creating a popup in oAuth2 auth code flow in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0

I'm using [react-simple-oauth2-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-oauth2-login) to login users using OAuth2 auth code flow. This library uses a popup and in that it performs the auth cycle. I want to disable this popup so that the auth cycle happens in the parent window only. Is there any way to achieve this in this library or maybe using a different library?

Thanks in advance.